# Pandas: .groupby().size() and percentages

Tags: python, pandas, bioinformatics

I have a DataFrame that originates from a `df.groupby().size()` operation, and looks like this:

```
Localization                           RNA level      
cytoplasm                              1 Non-expressed     7
                                       2 Very low         13
                                       3 Low               8
                                       4 Medium            6
                                       5 Moderate          8
                                       6 High              2
                                       7 Very high         6
cytoplasm & nucleus                    1 Non-expressed     5
                                       2 Very low          8
                                       3 Low               2
                                       4 Medium           10
                                       5 Moderate         16
                                       6 High              6
                                       7 Very high         5
cytoplasm & nucleus & plasma membrane  1 Non-expressed     6
                                       2 Very low          3
                                       3 Low               3
                                       4 Medium            7
                                       5 Moderate          8
                                       6 High              4
                                       7 Very high         1
```

What I want to do is to calculate the separate occurrences (i.e. the last column coming from `.size()`) as a percentage of the total number of occurrences in the applicable `Localization`.

For example: there are a total of 50 occurrences in the `cytoplasm` localisation (7 + 13 + 8 + 6 + 8 + 2 + 6), yielding 14 and 26 % for the `Non-expressed` and `Very low` RNA-levels, respectively.

Is there a nice way of doing this? I've been going about it with what I think is a very roundabout way, i.e. making a new DataFrame for every `Localization` and working on from there, but there's a lot of lines and the problem of having to merge all the resulting DataFrames in the end. I'm hoping there's a smarter way of doing it, at least!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Here is the complete example based on pandas [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html), [`sum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html) functions.
The basic idea is to group data based on `'Localization'` and to apply a function on group.

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO
#For Python 2, replace previous line with: from StringIO import StringIO

data = \
"""Localization,RNA level,Size
cytoplasm                            ,1 Non-expressed, 7
cytoplasm                            ,2 Very low     ,13
cytoplasm                            ,3 Low          , 8
cytoplasm                            ,4 Medium       , 6
cytoplasm                            ,5 Moderate     , 8
cytoplasm                            ,6 High         , 2
cytoplasm                            ,7 Very high    , 6
cytoplasm & nucleus                  ,1 Non-expressed, 5
cytoplasm & nucleus                  ,2 Very low     , 8
cytoplasm & nucleus                  ,3 Low          , 2
cytoplasm & nucleus                  ,4 Medium       ,10
cytoplasm & nucleus                  ,5 Moderate     ,16
cytoplasm & nucleus                  ,6 High         , 6
cytoplasm & nucleus                  ,7 Very high    , 5
cytoplasm & nucleus & plasma membrane,1 Non-expressed, 6
cytoplasm & nucleus & plasma membrane,2 Very low     , 3
cytoplasm & nucleus & plasma membrane,3 Low          , 3
cytoplasm & nucleus & plasma membrane,4 Medium       , 7
cytoplasm & nucleus & plasma membrane,5 Moderate     , 8
cytoplasm & nucleus & plasma membrane,6 High         , 4
cytoplasm & nucleus & plasma membrane,7 Very high    , 1"""

# Create the dataframe
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data))
df['Localization'].str.strip()
df['RNA level'].str.strip()
df['Size'].astype(int)
df['Percent'] = df.groupby('Localization')['Size'].transform(lambda x: x/sum(x))
```

Comment: you should use ``df['RNA level'].str.strip()`` for vectorized string cleaning (rather than converters), and ``df['Size'].astype(int)`` for vectorized int conversions

Comment: your groupby can be collapsed down to: ``df.groupby('Localization')['Size'].transform(lambda x: x/len(x))``

Comment: You mean ``df.groupby('Localization')['Size'].transform(lambda x: x/sum(x))``