# Pandas groupwise percentage

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, percentage

How can I calculate a group-wise percentage in pandas?

similar to 
[Pandas: .groupby().size() and percentages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23627782/pandas-groupby-size-and-percentages) or [Pandas Very Simple Percent of total size from Group by](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29299078/pandas-very-simple-percent-of-total-size-from-group-by) I want to calculate the percentage of a value per group.

How can I achieve this?

My dataset is structured like

```
ClassLabel, Field
```

Initially, I aggregate on both `ClassLbel` and `Field` like

```
grouped = mydf.groupby(['Field', 'ClassLabel']).size().reset_index()
grouped = grouped.rename(columns={0: 'customersCountPerGroup'})
```

Now I would like to know the percentage of customers in each group on a per group basis. The groups total can be obtained like `mydf.groupby(['Field']).size()` but I neither can merge that as a column nor am I sure this is the right approach - there must be something simpler.

## edit

I want to calculate the percentage only based on a single group e.g. 3 0 0.125 1 0.250 the sum of 0 + 1 --> 0.125 + 0.250 = 0,375 and use this value to devide / normalize grouped and not grouped.sum()
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IIUC you can use:

```
mydf = pd.DataFrame({'Field':[1,1,3,3,3],
                   'ClassLabel':[4,4,4,4,4],
                   'A':[7,8,9,5,7]})

print (mydf)
   A  ClassLabel  Field
0  7           4      1
1  8           4      1
2  9           4      3
3  5           4      3
4  7           4      3

grouped = mydf.groupby(['Field', 'ClassLabel']).size()
print (grouped)
Field  ClassLabel
1      4             2
3      4             3
dtype: int64

print (100 * grouped / grouped.sum())
Field  ClassLabel
1      4             40.0
3      4             60.0
dtype: float64
```

---

```
grouped = mydf.groupby(['Field', 'ClassLabel']).size().reset_index()
grouped = grouped.rename(columns={0: 'customersCountPerGroup'})
print (grouped)
   Field  ClassLabel  customersCountPerGroup
0      1           4                       2
1      3           4                       3

grouped['per'] = 100 * grouped.customersCountPerGroup / grouped.customersCountPerGroup.sum()
print (grouped)
   Field  ClassLabel  customersCountPerGroup   per
0      1           4                       2  40.0
1      3           4                       3  60.0
```

EDIT by comment:

```
mydf = pd.DataFrame({'Field':[1,1,3,3,3,4,5,6],
                   'ClassLabel':[0,0,0,1,1,0,0,6],
                   'A':[7,8,9,5,7,5,6,4]})

print (mydf)

grouped = mydf.groupby(['Field', 'ClassLabel']).size()
df =  grouped / grouped.sum()

df = (grouped / df.groupby(level=0).transform('sum')).reset_index(name='new')
print (df)
   Field  ClassLabel       new
0      1           0  8.000000
1      3           0  2.666667
2      3           1  5.333333
3      4           0  8.000000
4      5           0  8.000000
5      6           6  8.000000
```

Comment: But if I do not want to use `grouped.sum()` but really perform this operation for each group separately e.g. use the sum of class 0 and class 1 for field 1 as the total. How can I access that?

Comment: Sorry, can you add it to question, what is desired output from input? the best is modify or use my sample or create another one, because I am not sure if I understand you.

Comment: ok, i add solution, but I am not still sure, if I understand you. please check it.

Comment: Thanks. Indeed this is what I wanted. Thanks a lot. How could I add the column created by `grouped / sum_grouped` to  the df created by `.reset_index()`? I only get incompatible index of inserted column

Comment: Try `.reset_index(name='new')`

Comment: `df = (mydf.groupby(['Field', 'ClassLabel']).size() / df.groupby(level=0).transform('sum')).reset_index(name='new')
`

Comment: Indeed this is seems to work but it seems to be a very time consuming operation compared to the statements above which were instant.

Comment: I simplify it, now it is faster.