# groupby and percentile calculation in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like this

```
name event  spending
abc   A       500
abc   B       300
abc   C       200
xyz   A       2000
xyz   D       1000
```

So i need a groupby name and event and calculate respective percentile...so output should be like

```
name  event  spending_percentile
abc   A       50%
abc   B       30%
abc   C       20%
xyz   A       66.67%
xyz   D       33.33%
```

Please guide how to do this in pandas Dataframe.

Comment: related and probable dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39388820/pandas-groupwise-percentage

Comment: @EdChum: sorry, did not google properly (was in hurry)..Thanks, that link helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you need [`transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html):

```
df['spending_percentile'] = df['spending'].div(df.groupby('name')['spending']
                                                 .transform(sum)).mul(100)
print (df)
  name event  spending  spending_percentile
0  abc     A       500            50.000000
1  abc     B       300            30.000000
2  abc     C       200            20.000000
3  xyz     A      2000            66.666667
4  xyz     D      1000            33.333333
```

Comment: Great Help..Thanks @jezrael